# Difference between a defined machineKey or just AutoGenerate without IsolateApps?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

We have an single iis website setup, and inside this website there are three child applications - a rest api, a client, and a background job server (i.e. the path looks like Server/Sites/Web Site/apps1-2-3). These child apps all target a single application pool but one that is exclusive to this site/3 apps. We need to share data protection between the the api and the job server for cookie auth as well as identity verification (email / password reset tokens).

For the cookies we found suggestions to setup a data protection provider with a shared keystore for the two child apps - basically changing:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    ...
```

To

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = Common.Constants.AuthenticationTypes.IdentityApplication,
    TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
        new DataProtectorShim(
            DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\\keyShare")),
                builder => builder.SetApplicationName("AppName"))
                            .CreateProtector(
                                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                                Common.Constants.AuthenticationTypes.IdentityApplication,
                                "v2")
        )),
    ...
```

This works for the cookie auth, but doesn't fix the problem of the identity verifications.

We later discovered that we could just specifiy a machineKey section in root sites web.config (the entire root website is literally just a web.config with a redirect to the path of the child client app. Since this causes the key to cascade to the child applications so they all have the same key.  While this seemed to solve all of the above problems for cookies and identity we didn't like having the machine key in source control and having just moved away from encrytped web.configs in favor of azure's key vault we aren't looking to go back.

We noticed however you could set the machine key to auto generate in IIS but it wouldn't allow the machine key to be shared across the child applications, that is until you remove the `IsolateApps` keyword that's added by default leaving you with:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate" validationKey="AutoGenerate" />
</system.web>
```

Removing the `IsolateApps` keyword it now shares the machineKey across between both apps and cookies/identity work as expected. But we can't really seem to nail down the security risks involved with removing `IsolateApps`. Some places seem to indicate that it's just for the website's child applications, other sources indicate that it's every application on the server. There are a number of neighboring sites also running on our server, but they are all under their own website and their own application pool. It also doesn't instill much confidence that pretty much every single example we can find always includes IsolateApps with some comment about preventing it from being shared with other web applications (but which applications!)

It seems that if it's just allowing the generated key to be shared between the child applications of our one site/app pool - exactly as it would if I just generated the fixed machineKey then it's the better approach for us as no known machine key has to be saved in our web.config.

Comment: you could use the IsolateByAppId option which will generate the different keys based on the application's AppDomainAppID.the default AutoGenerate,IsolateApps setting does not necessarily provides you with unique keys, but if you host your apps in their own application pools which are running with ApplicationPoolIdentity, and you use IsolateByAppId instead of IsolateApps you can be sure, that your apps will use unique autogenerated keys. you can get more details from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388589/11147346)